# How to work on new excel sheets without hanging when macro runs background

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which is in loop that takes data from excel sheets every second and insert into mysql database.This process will takes place when I click start button and executes until I presses stop button. My problem is when I open other excel sheets it hangs and I am unable to click on cell as it gives loading symbol.I want macro to run at background at the same time I want to work on excel sheets.

Macro should not be stopped at any cost even for a second because we are retriving the commodity and currency prices from the sheets and it will change every second. So what I need is when I click start button macro should run at background in loop and it should not disturbed at the same time I should be able to work on new excel sheets without any hindrance.

```
Sub StartDataUpdate()
    TimerActive = True
    UpdateData
End Sub

Sub StopDataUpdate()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateData()
    If TimerActive Then
    ConnectDB
    Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
     With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Price")
            For rowCursor = 2 To 10
                 //Code to insert data in database
            Next
     End With

    Set rs1.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    RepeatUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

Above is part of my code, kindly give a suggestion.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have another computer just sitting there doing that and work on your machine...

Comment: As said in your other post: Open another instance of Excel: https://excelgorilla.com/excel/general/open-multiple-instances-excel/

Comment: @Alex de Jong How to open existing workbooks in new instance? Actually I am new to excel, vba.Code was already written and given to me. Kindly help.

Comment: In a new instance you can just go to File->Open. Or do you want to open other files automatically?

Comment: @Alex de Jong Now it works well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to consider the complexity of the code that gather the data and insert it in the database.

Since you want the user experience in the excel workbook to be as unencumbered as possible, this code needs to be very very quick to execute.

If it's not, then you need to move all the time consuming activities out of the macro, for example by writing some king of demon listening to the data and doing the database updates at its leisure time.

Once you've done this and you've managed to write two compact functions, one to gather the data and the other to send it to the db (or to write an external demon that does that), then you can use code like this to do your trick:

```
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventUpdate"

Public Sub EventUpdate()
    If(CanISendData) Then
            data = gatherData()
            sendData(data)
    End If
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventUpdate"
End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime